# Android EditText removes Emojis

Tags: android, android-edittext, emoji, imagespan

I have just build a simple chat aplication, which consists only of a single `EditText`. I set `inputType` to `textShortMessage`. Now you are able to type in emojis.

The problem is that there are certain combinations in which emojis are not even entered or disappear.

Code looks like this (most of it was generated by AndroidStudio, I added the `TextWatcher`):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean updateText = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (updateText) {
                    updateText = false;
                    editText.setText(editText.getText());    // cause problems
                } else
                    updateText = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is possible to type in characters and emojis (which are `ImageSpan` I guess) via keyboard (I use the standard keyboard of the virtual device). But some combinations do not work as expected.

If you put the cursor *behind* a normal character but *before* an emoji and you try to type another emoji, it will not appear.

You could try to produce following patterns by interting the middlepart last (C is a char, E an emoji):

```
`CEC`   works
`CEE`   works NOT!
`EEE`   works
`EEC`   works
```

This problem seem to be caused by `editText.setText(editText.getText())`. But I do not know, why this works most of the time but only somtimes not.

++EDIT++

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
if (updateText)
    System.out.println("X "+editText.getText().length());
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (updateText) {
        updateText = false;
        System.out.println("A " + editText.getText().length());
        editText.setText(editText.getText());
        System.out.println("B "+editText.getText().length());
    } else
        updateText = true;
}
```

If you type in a normal char: X is 1 (or with emoji 2 because it may consists of two chars) less than A and B. This also works with

```
//editText.setText(editText.getText());
```

If you cause a problem: X = A = B

This is very disturbing, because this means it seems that A 'knows' that the text will be changed one line ahead in advance. Normally I would expect that if the `setText(...);` line causes problems that the length of the text **before** this line (A) must be 1 (or 2) bigger than B and the emoji is lost during `setText(...);`. But A = B so the emoji is lost **before** `setText(...);` is even reached.

This could also be observed by using `onTextChanged` method. The length of the text (in case of error) in this method is equals to the length before text changed (X). It seems the input is not even registered.